# How to generate a custom JMeter report from aggregate report statistics?

Tags: jmeter

JMeter produces detailed report as dashboard but I would like to create my own summary as a simple HTML page with relevant execution parameters and few samplers statistics in a table. As a global summary, this generation may be triggered once at the end of test plan execution.

Inspired from [JMeter JSR223 Listener for ExtentReports needs improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601473/jmeter-jsr223-listener-for-extentreports-needs-improvement) it looks like possible to integrate such report generation as a JSR223 listener.

If such a listener is the correct option, how to retrieve (or compute again) samplers statistics already available in Aggregate Report listener like count, avarage, min, max, percentil?

Any alternative way is welcomed too. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a CSV version of the Aggregate Report using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd) like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv AggregateReport.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/test/result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Then you can create a simple HTML page from it using i.e. [CSV to HTML Table](https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table) project or the same [FreeMarker engine](https://freemarker.apache.org/) which JMeter uses for the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)